# How do i make a 2d key array in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

i'm fairly new to php programming, and just regular programming and i have a question to ask.
I have 2 arrays that contain the x and y values for co-ordinates.

```
$datay = array();
$datax = array();
```

I need to have these arrays for matted in a json encoded array like :

```
"x": 0,
"y": 0,
```

it has to be a 2d array with this for each element in datax or datay array, since both will be the same length. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sample

```
$result_data = array();
foreach ($datay as $y_key => $y_value) {
   $result_data[] = array('x'=> $datax[$y_key], 'y' => $y_value);
}
json_encode($result_data);
```